# How to show a bootstrap modal from another component?

Tags: angular-dart

I'm building an app to manage some users, where i have a page to list them. On each user i have some buttons to make some actions on them, like edit them or delete them.

When the delete button is pressed, i would like to have a modal to show up and ask if you really wawnt to delete the user. As i may be using this modal in other places, i thought i should make it kind of generic to receive the different messages i want to show, so i built a component for it.

I've searched through some examples, but i couldn't find one similar to mine.

I've made the template for the modal and the component to back it up, but i don't know how to show it, for example, on a button click.

Any help is appretiated :)
Thanks

EDIT: i'm trying to use bootstrap modals

Answer (score 0):

use bootbox instead of making a modal from scratch. they can be perfectly used for delete confirm or alerts. I use them.  http://bootboxjs.com/. It is also available for angularjs.